# Cannot copydb from a remote MongoDB machine. "namespace query failed remote-db-name.system.namespaces"

Tags: mongodb

I have a remote mongodb database, and I want to make a copy to my local machine. I have a read-only user on the remote machine, and I must connect to a slave instance from a replica set.

I am trying to run the `copydb` command, but this is what happens:

```
> mongo localhost
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: localhost
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.runCommand(
  {         
    "copydb" : 1,         
    "fromhost" : "thisismyurl_blhblbhlblh:31337",         
    "fromdb" : "remote-db-name",         
    "todb" : "local-db-name",         
    "username" : "myusername",         
    "key" : "543827989734kjjkf3997834897",         
    "slaveOK" : true
  }
)
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "namespace query failed remote-db-name.system.namespaces"
}
>
```

By the way, I can connect the mongo client to the remote machine with the same username and password, and perform queries with no problems.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you copy database from secondary? Do you use md5 and nonce for key generation from password (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/copydb/#dbcmd.copydb)? Same result for db.copyDatabase(...) ?  I guess it might be that issue https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5577

Comment: it might be that you need the "slaveOK" to be "slaveOk"?